# Why is the vertical alignment of my html button in a <td> lost when I add an image?

Tags: html, css, button, html-table

[image]I have buttons where I have normally added just text. In this way the vert. alignment of the buttons in the `<td>` is ok.(Code-1).

But when I add also an image to the button, then the alignment of the button is lost.The `<td>` height gets higher and the button is aligned to the bottom. What is faulty?

```css
.td_button_bar {
  background-color: #eaf2f8;
  border: none;
  left: 10px;
}

.button {
  width: 75px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eaf2f8;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #aed6f1;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  color: #212f3c;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
Code-1 vert.alignment OK:
<table>
  <tr class="tr_button_bar">
    <td class="td_button_bar" align="left" valign="middle">
      &nbsp;<button class="button">Connect</button> &nbsp;
      <button class="button">Disconnect</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
Code-2 vert.alignment Not OK:
<table>
  <tr class="tr_button_bar">
    <td class="td_button_bar" align="left" valign="middle">
      &nbsp;<button class="button"><img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/923/71/png-transparent-computer-icons-connect-miscellaneous-angle-technology-thumbnail.png" width="20" height="20" align="middle">Connect</button> &nbsp;
      <button class="button"><img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/627/934/png-transparent-computer-icons-electrical-connector-ac-power-plugs-and-sockets-plug-in-connect-miscellaneous-computer-program-electrical-connector-thumbnail.png" width="20" height="20" align="middle">Disconnect</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a [mcve]. Please do so next time you ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin-top = 0;` and `padding = 0 0 0 0;` on image that will help to adjust your image and text inside the button.

Comment: Last question to the topic: My button icon images are not always in the same size. I want that my text is always  x pixel up above the the button bottom, independent how big the mage is. How can I do that?

Comment: @Mdarende The answer is provided by Answerer not me ;) I only edited to highlight the css styles.